# How to load 3D object using AMFLoader in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to three.js.I am trying to load 3d object on web browser using AMFLoader and STLLoader in three.js. Both AMFLoader and STLLoader has same problem. The 3d object doesn't render on web browser and also doesn't show any error. I don't know how to fix this.Below is my code snippet which I have tried with AMFLoader.

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>three.js webgl - loaders - amf loader</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <style>
   body {
    font-family: Monospace;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
  <body>

  <script src="three.js"></script>

  <script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>

  <script src="AMFLoader.js"></script>

  <script src="Detector.js"></script>
  <script src="stats.min.js"></script>

  <script>

   if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

   var container, stats;

   var camera, controls, scene, renderer;

   init();
   animate();

   function init() {
                
                // camera  
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 7;
    camera.position.set( -0.140892, 0.00959548, 0.0602311);


    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x999999 );

    scene.add( camera );

    // light
    ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
    scene.add(ambient);

                keyLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(30, 100%, 75%)'), 1.0);
                keyLight.position.set(-100, 0, 100);

                fillLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(240, 100%, 75%)'), 0.75);
                fillLight.position.set(100, 0, 100);

                backLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
                backLight.position.set(100, 0, -100).normalize();
    /*var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
    dirLight.position.set( 200, 200, 1000 ).normalize();

    camera.add( dirLight );
    camera.add( dirLight.target );*/

    var loader = new THREE.AMFLoader();
    loader.load( 'Method1-ConeThenCube.amf', function ( object ) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff5533, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200 } );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( object, material );
    scene.add( object );

    } );

    // renderer

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    stats = new Stats();
    container.appendChild( stats.dom );

    //

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

   }

   function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

   }

   function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

    stats.update();

   }

  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Help me to fix this problem.

Comment: please refer this [example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_amf.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response.I referred this example but the object doesn't render on the web browser and also doesn't show any error. Can you help me out what is the problem with my code and how to solve it?

Comment: The `AMFLoader` supports progress and error callbacks in the load function,  Please change your `load` function like this and check for any errors in the console,

`var loader = new THREE.AMFLoader();
loader.load( 'Method1-ConeThenCube.amf', function ( object ) {

 scene.add( object );

}, function( xhr ){

 console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

}, function( error ){

 console.log( error );

} );`

Comment: also make sure that the object you trying to load is in the correct path, otherwise specify the path to the object in the load function

Comment: I have tried this code and it shows this statement in the console:error { target: XMLHttpRequest, isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, eventPhase: 0, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, defaultPrevented: false, composed: false, … }

Comment: it means that there is no error. right?

Comment: I think you are trying to load the amf model from an incorrect path, Please change the `console.log( error );` to 
`console.log( "Error : " );
console.log( error.target.status );`
If the status is 404, then you are trying to load the file from an incorrect path

Comment: I have added this statement : console.log( "Error : " ); console.log( error.target.status ); and it shows only blank screen and in the console it shows Error : 0. There might be problem with lighting and camera perspective?

Comment: Can you post the updated code. If possible please add a fiddle too

Comment: for some reasons your request for the file `Method1-ConeThenCube.amf` is failing. I don't know what is the exact issue and one possibility is that, you are trying to load the file from the directory in which the HTML file is located. You might have stored the amf file in a different path

Comment: can you share your email id if it is possible? I will share the code file.